# Dynamic Dropdown menu Design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am trying to create a Dynamic Dropdown menu class
which contains

a class

> Menu

and `MenuItem` class.

menu class Iterates over the menu Items. using methods

```
function load
function hasNext
function next
function current
```

And menutItem class contains information about like `URL, LinkText, IsActive`

but my problem is the `menuitem` may have in turn also Children. And I am unable to solve this problem, how should I store and display the Children of a `MenuItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set one patent_id for first level menu has patent_id = 0 and all other have specific value
set function hasChild() and pass this parent id as a argument and based on this generate the child menu
call this function recursive so it will generate all tree structure